# Scope command problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, scalebox

I have a latex document in which I have drawn a figure with two tikzpictures, I need to place the two tikzpictures in specific locations. for this I used the "scope" command with "`shift=`". In my document the tikzpictures are scaled with the "`scalebox`" command, the latter poses a problem, it leaves a space before the figure to be drawn, and when I remove the "scalebox" command I get the desired result but I must use the "scalebox" command.

Below is a slight example (not my example)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
dhdghg hdg hdgh dghg g dhdhfghdgfdhgfhdfghdfghfg hdfghgfhffh dghfgdhfdhfgdhfgdhfgdhh d hfg dh gdhf gdh fghdgfdhgfh hfgdhfg hdgf 
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\scalebox{0.4}{%
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,16);
}
\scalebox{0.85}{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(6,3)},scale=0.85]
\draw[red,line width=1.2pt] (0,0) rectangle (3,4);
\end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
dhdghg hdg hdgh dghg g dhdhfghdgfdhgfhdfghdfghfg hdfghgfhffh dghfgdhfdhfgdhfgdhfgdhh d hfg dh gdhf gdh fghdgfdhgfh hfgdhfg hdgf 
\end{document}
```

[image]

And when i use "`scale=`", some drawings (those with decoration like zigzag) are not scaled. I give you another example.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns,decorations.markings,shadings,decorations.shapes}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
dhdghg hdg hdgh dghg g dhdhfghdgfdhgfhdfghdfghfg hdfghgfhffh dghfgdhfdhfgdhfgdhfgdhh d hfg dh gdhf gdh fghdgfdhgfh hfgdhfg hdgf 
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.4]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (8,16);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(-10,2)}]
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=black] (3,1.5)--(1,1.5)--(1,2.2)--(3,2.2)--cycle;
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.1,2.4)--(2.9,2.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.2,2.9)--(2.8,2.8);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.24,3.4)--(2.74,3.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.3,3.9)--(2.68,3.8);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.37,4.4)--(2.62,4.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.43,4.9)--(2.54,4.8);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.5,5.38)--(2.48,5.28);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.56,5.88)--(2.42,5.78);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.64,6.38)--(2.36,6.28);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.7,6.88)--(2.3,6.78);
\draw[line width=1.2pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (3,2.2)--(2.35,7);
\draw[line width=1pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (1.65,7)--(1,2.2);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[scale=0.3,shift={(-10,2)}]
\draw[line width=1.2pt,color=black] (3,1.5)--(1,1.5)--(1,2.2)--(3,2.2)--cycle;
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.1,2.4)--(2.9,2.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.2,2.9)--(2.8,2.8);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.24,3.4)--(2.74,3.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.3,3.9)--(2.68,3.8);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.37,4.4)--(2.62,4.3);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.43,4.9)--(2.54,4.8);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.5,5.38)--(2.48,5.28);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.56,5.88)--(2.42,5.78);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.64,6.38)--(2.36,6.28);
\draw[line width=1.2pt] (1.7,6.88)--(2.3,6.78);
\draw[line width=1.2pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (3,2.2)--(2.35,7);
\draw[line width=1pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (1.65,7)--(1,2.2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
dhdghg hdg hdgh dghg g dhdhfghdgfdhgfhdfghdfghfg hdfghgfhffh dghfgdhfdhfgdhfgdhfgdhh d hfg dh gdhf gdh fghdgfdhgfh hfgdhfg hdgf 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `\scalebox` inside TikZ. You already use `scale=.85` in one place and you could use `scale=.4` in the other. TikZ has no control over the space around a TikZ picture. Since you place the TikZ picture inside the float environment `figure` LaTeX places your picture according to its rule.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel but the placement specifier `H` from `float` means "exactly here", so I can understand the confusion as to why there is this much space inserted.

Comment: @Skillmon That space is inserted because while the content will be scaled down, PGF doesn't know about it when determining the bounding box and still uses the full 16, i.e. 16cm.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel my comment was merely regarding "Since you place the TikZ picture inside the float environment [...]".

Comment: Thank you for your response. when i use "scale=", some drawings (those with decoration like zigzag) are not scaled. I give you another example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scale{0.4}` multiplies all coordinates by the given 0.4, but not the pic,

- we can manually modify `segment length = 0.2mm`(5mm x 0.4) and `amplitude = 0.4mm`(1mm x 0.4)
- use `transform canvas={scale=0.4}`

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns,decorations.markings,shadings,decorations.shapes}
   \begin{document}
   \tikzset{
       line width=1.2pt,
       pics/piczigzag/.style={
               code={
                       \draw(3,1.5)--(1,1.5)--(1,2.2)--(3,2.2)--cycle;
                       \draw  (1.1,2.4)--(2.9,2.3);
                       \draw  (1.2,2.9)--(2.8,2.8);
                       \draw  (1.24,3.4)--(2.74,3.3);
                       \draw  (1.3,3.9)--(2.68,3.8);
                       \draw  (1.37,4.4)--(2.62,4.3);
                       \draw  (1.43,4.9)--(2.54,4.8);
                       \draw  (1.5,5.38)--(2.48,5.28);
                       \draw  (1.56,5.88)--(2.42,5.78);
                       \draw  (1.64,6.38)--(2.36,6.28);
                       \draw  (1.7,6.88)--(2.3,6.78);
                       \draw[line width=1pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (3,2.2)--(2.35,7);
                       \draw[line width=1pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (1.65,7)--(1,2.2);
                   },
           }
   }
   %  with scale, don't work, Multiplies all coordinates by the given hfactori but not the ndoe th pic, 
   % \begin{tikzpicture}
   % \pic [red] at (0,0) {piczigzag};
   % \pic[scale=0.4,blue] at (4,0) {piczigzag};
   % \end{tikzpicture}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \pic [red] at (0,0) {piczigzag};
       \pic[transform canvas={scale=0.4},blue] at (10,0) {piczigzag};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

EDIT: As you can see, it is surprising that the figures are not aligned.

I added a grid and a dashed line from the origin of the picture and the first visible point of the colored figure.

[image]

The offset of (1,1.5) in the red figure is (0.4,0.6) in the blue figure 1 x 0.4 and 1.5 x 0.4

The situation can be restored by:

- re-enter all the coordonnes...
- shift with `shift={(-1,-1.5)`

  ```
   \pic [red,shift={(-1,-1.5)}] (A) at (0,0) {piczigzag};
   \pic[transform canvas={scale=0.4},blue,shift={(-1,-1.5)}] at (7,0) {piczigzag};
  ```

Remark: the coordinate (7,0) sont (2.8,0) --> 7 x 0.4

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns,decorations.markings,shadings,decorations.shapes}
    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{
            %line width=1.2pt,<-- modif
            pics/piczigzag/.style={
                            code={
                                    \draw [dashed,thick](0,0)-| (1,1.5);%<-- added
                                    \draw (3,1.5)--(1,1.5)--(1,2.2)--(3,2.2)--cycle;
                                    \draw  (1.1,2.4)--(2.9,2.3);
                                    \draw  (1.2,2.9)--(2.8,2.8);
                                    \draw  (1.24,3.4)--(2.74,3.3);
                                    \draw  (1.3,3.9)--(2.68,3.8);
                                    \draw  (1.37,4.4)--(2.62,4.3);
                                    \draw  (1.43,4.9)--(2.54,4.8);
                                    \draw  (1.5,5.38)--(2.48,5.28);
                                    \draw  (1.56,5.88)--(2.42,5.78);
                                    \draw  (1.64,6.38)--(2.36,6.28);
                                    \draw  (1.7,6.88)--(2.3,6.78);
                                    \draw[line width=1pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (3,2.2)--(2.35,7);
                                    \draw[line width=1pt,decoration = {zigzag,segment length = 5mm, amplitude = 1mm},decorate] (1.65,7)--(1,2.2);
                                    },
                    }
    }
    %  with scale, don't work, Multiplies all coordinates by the given hfactori but not the ndoe th pic, 
    % \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt]
    % \pic [red] at (0,0) {piczigzag};
    % \pic[scale=0.4,blue] at (4,0) {piczigzag};
    % \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt]
            \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid(10,10);
            \draw [help lines] [step=0.1](2,0) grid(4,1);
            \pic [red] (A) at (0,0) {piczigzag};
            \pic[transform canvas={scale=0.4},blue] at (7,0) {piczigzag};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt]
            \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid(10,10);
            \draw [help lines] [step=0.1](2,0) grid(4,1);
            \pic [red,shift={(-1,-1.5)}] (A) at (0,0) {piczigzag};
            \pic[transform canvas={scale=0.4},blue,shift={(-1,-1.5)}] at (7,0) {piczigzag};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

EDIT2: bug `line width=1.2 pt` misplaced

Comment: Interesting answer (+1! Why blue image is move down? I expect that bot images will be align at their bottom ...

Comment: @Zarko `transform canvas` doesn't update the bounding box. Just put text before and after the `tikzpicture` to see that the bottom of the red one is aligned at the baseline and blue one isn't even inside the bounding box. It is lower because the lowest point inside the pic is *y* = 1.5 for the red one and *y* = 0.6 = 0.4 × 1.5 for the blue one. The `at` position of the pic only specifies the origin of the pics coordinate system. They're both above the origin of the picture itself. Add `\draw (0,0) grid (10,2);` at the start of the picture to see the global coordinate system.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks for your comment, I edited my answer

Comment: Nice edit. A bit shorter picture code:  `\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt] \pic [red] at (0,-1.5) {piczigzag}; \pic[transform canvas={scale=0.4},blue] at (10,-1.5) {piczigzag};  \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you for explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers (@pascal974 and @Zarko)